# PrimeFaces Grid CSS not applied since css classes are not found?

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to get the PrimeFaces Grid CSS working, but it won't work. I followed the example on the PrimeFaces page, but when I run it through the browser all the DIV entries are shown in a vertical list. Where is the error?
I have the following XHTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html   xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head/>
    <h:body>
        <div class="ui-grid">
            <div class="ui-grid-row">
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">Col1</div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">Col2</div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">Col2</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-grid">
            <div class="ui-grid-row">
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-8">8</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-grid">
            <div class="ui-grid-row">
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-row">
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-row">
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive">
            <div class="ui-grid-row">
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-8">8</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-fixed">
            <div class="ui-grid-row">
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-8">8</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If there is no PF component on page, you need to add it manually.

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="grid/grid.css" library="primefaces" />
```

Comment: Taht's not the truth. Since version 5.1 Grid layout should work out of the box.

Answer (score 6):

it seems like primefaces.css not included. so should be least one primefaces component in xhtml page. try this:

```xhtml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head/>
<h:body>
    <p:outputPanel>
        <div class="ui-grid">
            <div class="ui-grid-row">
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">Col1</div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">Col2</div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">Col2</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-grid">
            <div class="ui-grid-row">
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-8">8</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-grid">
            <div class="ui-grid-row">
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-row">
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-row">
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive">
            <div class="ui-grid-row">
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-8">8</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-fixed">
            <div class="ui-grid-row">
                <div class="ui-grid-col-4">4</div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-8">8</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </p:outputPanel>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually I run into the same issue.
The important part is, that the grid Layout is only supported from version 5.1 on!